# How to search multiple keys from predefined array?

Tags: php, arrays

i have predefined array of categories like this in `key => value` pair

```
$all_categories = array (
                    1 => 'friends',
                    2 => 'family',
                    3 => 'personal',
                    4 => 'public'
);
```

and i have new small array like this which are only `values`.

```
$searched_categories = array('family','public');
```

Now how can i get the keys from `$all_categories` array having values as `$searched_categories` ?

i want output like this

```
$output_array = array(2,4);
```

---

i can get single key using `array_search` but is there a prebuilt function for this ? or i have to create  a loop to `array_search`  all the values i have ?

---

is this proper way of achieving this ?

```
$output_array = array ();
foreach ($searched_categories as $value){
    $key = array_search($value, $all_categories );
    $output_array  = $key;
}
```

Comment: use a loop and move on to the next problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$all_categories = array (1 => 'friends', 2 => 'family', 3 => 'personal', 4 => 'public');

$searched_categories = array('family','public');

$output_array = array_keys(
    array_intersect(
        $all_categories,
        $searched_categories
    )
);
var_dump($output_array);
```

Comment: Are there any reason to use this one instead of array_search ? Smaller complexity maybe ?

Comment: Simpler because you don't need to loop, just uses two built-in functions, no need for an `if` test, so probably also micro-scopically faster too

Comment: Yeah, I noticed about the if check at the same time I asked you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach loop and `in_array`.

```
foreach($all_categories as $key => $category){ //loop through your categories array
    if(in_array($category, $searched_categories)){ //check if category is in searched_catgories
        $output_array[] = $key; //if category is there, then save the key to your new array
    }
}
```

`print_r($output_array);` will give you `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 )`

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` is doing the job, but you erase your array all the time and add $key regardless of the fact it could be equal to false from array_search :

```
foreach ($searched_categories as $value){
  $key = array_search($value, $all_categories );
  if ($key !== false) 
    $output_array[] = $key;
}
```